# Multi-master file synchronization

Tags: windows, linux, file-synchronization

I work on three machines at different times. I'm looking for a way to synchronize files between these machines. I've been using [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) which is pretty much exactly what I need, but it is poorly maintained, and I haven't been able to get it to work reliably.

I've thought about using Google Drive, but there are some files I don't want to synchronize. I'm working on a project that generates large files, and these must not be synchronized. A file size limit would be perfect.

Needs to work on both Linux and Windows. I have a internet-accessible machine I could install a server on, if that helps.

Comment: Unison does single-master synchronization (it has a central authority and every other copy is synchronized with that one). Is that what you want, or do you truly want multi-master synchronization, which significantly increases the risk of divergent changes?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [BitTorrent Sync](https://www.getsync.com/).

It works on both Linux and Windows (as well as quite a few other operating systems, including OS X, iOS, FreeBSD, Windows Phone, Fire OS, and Android).

It is currently maintained.

It does not require any connection to the internet, and can work entirely on your own network.  This makes syncing large files much less of an issue because local syncing is significantly faster than internet syncing.  Furthermore, you can specify which folders to sync, so you can exclude specific folders with large files.